# Alternate faster method for colorizing cells

Tags: excel, vba, performance, conditional-formatting

This part of my macro is for coloring the cells in row B, depending on their value and the value of the corresponding cell in row Q. It works well, but when the file is large (sometimes over 500,000 rows), this step can really slow down the entire execution of the macro. There is also the likelyhood that I will need to add more colors down the road, which will mean more IF statement lines which will slow it down even more.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 
Dim i As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range
For i = 11 To LastRow
  Set r1 = Range("B" & i)
  Set r2 = Range("Q" & i)
If r2 = "001111" Then r1.Interior.Color = vbGreen
If (r1 < 4 Or r1 > 0) And (r2 <> "001111") Then r1.Interior.Color = vbYellow
If (r1 > 3 Or r1 < 1) And (r2 <> "001111") Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
Next i
```

I tried using some code for conditional formatting on the entire row. This is much faster, but I wasn't able to figure out how to include the value of the cell in column Q as a condition. I was also limited to no more conditions than three.
Is there a way to accomplish this task in a way that is faster than my current code that will also allow for more conditions/colors in the future?

Comment: With conditional formatting, you'd use a rule based on a formula, e.g. for yellow: `=AND(OR($B11<4,$B11>0),$Q11<>"001111")`. But I suspect conditional formatting on 500k rows will still be slow.

Comment: I wonder if it would make any difference if you used If-Else and then you could get rid of `And (r2 <> "001111")`. But probably no getting away from the fact that 500k rows is not good in xl.

Comment: you can try loading everything into variant arrays, then you are only referencing the sheet once per loop instead of 7.

Comment: Don't you need `And` instead of `Or` in your test on `r1`? Don't think you'll ever pass anything the `vbRed` like this.

Comment: ^ @JvdV - do you mean `And` for `vbYellow`? `r1 < 4 And r1 > 0`? I think that's what you mean but just clarifying... and totally agree.

Comment: `(r1 < 4 Or r1 > 0)` will color everything yellow - all values satisfy this condition.

Comment: You might also consider assigning colors that are part of of the theme then you can easily change the theme colors later and it would update all the colors that are based on it.

Comment: Of course you are all correct about r1. It should read (r1 < 4 And r1  > 0). I should have spotted that sooner.

Answer (score 3):

Scratch my previous attempt. I do agree that `Range.AutoFilter` might even be better:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, rng As Range

With Sheet1

    'Get last used row of data and set range
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("B10:Q" & lr)

    'Apply first filter and color Green
    rng.AutoFilter 16, "001111"
    If rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(12).Count > 1 Then rng.Columns(1).Offset(1).Resize(lr - 10).Interior.Color = vbGreen

    'Apply second filter and color Yellow
    rng.AutoFilter 16, "<>*001111*"
    rng.AutoFilter 1, "<4", xlAnd, ">0"
    If rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(12).Count > 1 Then rng.Columns(1).Offset(1).Resize(lr - 10).Interior.Color = vbYellow

    'Apply third filter and color Red
    rng.AutoFilter 1, ">3", xlOr, "<1"
    If rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(12).Count > 1 Then rng.Columns(1).Offset(1).Resize(lr - 10).Interior.Color = vbRed

    'Remove AutoFilter
    rng.AutoFilter

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't remember... is there a character limit in the `Range` reference... i.e. does the length of `Join(Grn.Keys, ",")` matter?

Comment: Good question, if there appears to be then `Union` of ranges would be better.

Comment: @BigBen, I couldn't find a way to `Union` an array **directly**. Iteration came into play and tested it over thousands of rows and it became sluggish. I do now believe `Range.AutoFilter` might be better. Thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps yes. I don't know the performance of `AutoFilter` with 500k rows. I assume any approach that minimizes reading from/writing to the sheet is better. Side note - doesn't `.SpecialCells(...).Count` throw an error if there are no cells?

Comment: Just tested `Range.AutoFilter` on 1048575 rows. Just under 10 seconds for me. While `Union` took much longer. I'll leave the proper benchmarking for someone else. But to me the feel of `Range.AutoFilter` is less sluggish.

Comment: @BigBen, the headers are always visible, therefor I test for `>1` =)

Comment: Ah I missed the `10` in `Set rng = .Range("B10:Q" & lr)` :-) Duh.

Comment: The above code gives me the error "Run-time '1004' This can't be applied to the selected range. Select a single cell in a range and try again." This occurs with the line that reads 'rng.AutoFilter 16, "001111" '

Comment: What does your sheet look like? The only reason that should happen is if there is weirdness afoot in the sheet somehow. Because, for me, it works for an empty sheet, for a sheet with data from A11 to Q500.000 and even with empty columns inbetween, or an empty column "Q".

Comment: @ThomasKase, any luck yet?

Comment: I was able to use a variation on your example above to create a faster working solution than what I had before. Range.AutoFilter is a better solution for my application, and it speeds things up a lot. Unfortunately the data has expanded and now requires six colors and I will soon have to add a seventh. Still, I can filter over 500K rows of data for all six colors in about two and a half minutes. That's way faster than the nearly ten minutes it was taking for just three colors before. I'm still keeping an eye out for even faster solutions, but this works. Thanks again to you and everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the fastest would be to use an array? Maaaaybe some filter but I'm just gonna do the array for now:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("B11:B500000") = 1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("Q11:Q500000") = 2
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Dim r1
Dim r2

r1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("B11:B" & LastRow)
r2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("Q11:Q" & LastRow)

For i = LBound(r1) To UBound(r1)
    If r2(i, 1) = "001111" Then r1(i, 1) = vbGreen
    If (r1(i, 1) < 4 Or r1(i, 1) > 0) And (r2(i, 1) <> "001111") Then r1(i, 1) = vbYellow
    If (r1(i, 1) > 3 Or r1(i, 1) < 1) And (r2(i, 1) <> "001111") Then r1(i, 1) = vbRed
Next i

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    For i = LBound(r1) To UBound(r1)
        .Range("B" & 10 + i).Interior.Color = r1(i, 1)
    Next
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I wish we could apply the .Interior.Color all in one go but I can't get that to work. If someone else does, I'd really like to know too! This executes in 24.75s on my machine. Oh and I didn't check your logic for the <, > things, I just added an array. It will likely break if something unexpected is written in one of the cells, like a string or something.
Also I assume you use IFs instead of elseif for a reason? Not like it really matters if done in an array, just curious.

Comment: I think `AutoFilter` would really be a good alternative indeed =)

Comment: Yeah probably. But uhhh ahhhh, I really like your join ranges idea! Should make it much quicker. Will test that tomorrow.

Comment: The IFs without ElseIf is just lazy coding on my part. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll be fixing that as well.